# WooCommerce Rest API - Product category filter not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product, woocommerce-rest-api

I have created an app which is displaying some products using the WooCommerce Rest API.

I have applied a few filters and everything was looking good until I tried to apply a filter for the category

```
http://foo/wc-api/v3/products?filter[limit]=15&filter[category]=some-category&oauth_consumer_key=ck_xx&oauth_nonce=xx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=xx&oauth_version=1.0&filter%5Blimit%5D=15&filter%5Bcategory%5D=antioxidants&oauth_signature=xx%3D
```

Now I get the message

```
DENIED - The requested resource requires user authentication. (XHR): GET ...
```

Any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer (at least it's working for me)

You need to make the `filter[category]` the first parameter in your query string.

I'll let the guys know about this too.